# Power BI embedded report in Angular 7 code is not exported with visual filters applied

Tags: c#, angular, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

We have embedded Power BI report in Angular 7 code and when we try to export using Power BI provided service it is not exporting applied filters instead it download in initial state as PDF.

How to export all the pages with applied filters through Angular code?

```
 private _pbiconfig: any = {
    type: 'report',
    hostName: "https://app.powerbi.com/",
    accessToken: "",
    embedUrl: "",
    id: "",
    settings: {
      filterPaneEnabled: true,
      navContentPaneEnabled: true
    }
  };
```

Comment: Exporting API will make a separate connection to the underlying report, thus it can't see the current state of the user's connection (like filters, etc.). Before starting the export, you must use [BookmarksManager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerbi/powerbi-client/bookmarksmanager.bookmarksmanager) to capture the state of one or more pages as [bookmarks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/report-bookmarks) and pass it when you [call the API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file-in-group#pagebookmark).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some default filters, you can use reportLevelFilters in your report configuration, but if you want to export after applying filters from slicers or filter pane, you need to save it as bookmark and then export that bookmark.

**Reference:**

[Export Power BI embedded analytics reports API - Power BI | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to?tabs=gen2)

[Reports - Export To File - REST API (Power BI Power BI REST APIs) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file#powerbireportexportconfiguration)